# What is the relation between the coprime groups and direct product groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $U(n)$ be the set of positive integers that are less than $n$ and coprime to $n$. This set forms a group with multiplication modulo $n$.

Consider $U(15)$ and $U(20)$. Both have order 8, and both are isomorphic to the $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

What's the underlying connection? Is there a general result showing how the coprime groups are related to other groups?

Comment: You mean all *positive* integers, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U(n)$ is always Abelian, so it is a direct product of finite cyclic groups. If $n=uv$ where $(u,v)=1$ then by the Chinese remainder theorem, $U(n)$ is isomorphic to $U(u)\times U(v)$. Finally for every prime $p$, $U(p)=\{1,...,p-1\}$, a cyclic group of order $p-1$ because $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field and every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic. This explains your examples and many others.

**Addition** You may also use the fact that if $n=p^k$ or $n=2p^k$, $p>2$, prime, then $U(n)$ is a cyclic group of order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$. This is a [standard fact](https://brilliant.org/wiki/primitive-roots/#:%7E:text=A%20primitive%20root%20mod%20n,an%20integer%20z%20such%20that&text=a%E2%89%A1(gz(modn)).)

Comment: Your addition needs $p>2$. For $p=2$ we have $U(2^n)\cong C_2\times C_{2^{n-2}}$ (if $n\ge 2$).

Comment: OK, fixed. Thanks!